# Reset user input in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to do a script in tkinter. Good to know: I'm kind of new to python.
The script takes user input to find the user input on a server. First time I run the script it works fine, but when trying to find something new the script gives me the error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'` So im guesseing that the user input/Button needs to be reset some how. And I don´t understand why it works the first time and not the second time. 
I've tried to find a good way to do this, but I have failed. Please halp a newbie.

```
import requests, re, urllib.request
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.title("Find answer")
ttk.Label(window, text="What you wanna find: ").pack()
stuff = ttk.Entry(window)
stuff.pack()
frame = Frame(window, width=200, height=50)
frame.pack()
servers = ["192.168.8.3", "192.68.8.2"]

def find():
    global stuff
    stuff = stuff.get()
    stuff = stuff.lower()
    for server in servers:
        f = urllib.request.urlopen("http://"+server+"/find")
        result = f.read().decode('utf-8')
        lab = tk.Label(frame,text="server")
        lab.pack()
        print(server)

def clicked_start():
   find()   

start_btn = ttk.Button(text="Find the stuff", command=clicked_start)
start_btn.pack(fill="none")
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess the reason is that you redefine stuff

```
global stuff
stuff = stuff.get()
stuff = stuff.lower()
```

the variable is originally an Entry Object, you redefine it as a string

Try to use another variable, eg

```
global stuff
stuffcontent = stuff.get()
stuffcontent = stuffcontent.lower()
```